# Reading files bits and saving them

Tags: java, huffman-code

i have file reader which read entire file and write it's bits. 
I have this class which help reading:

```
import java.io.*;

public class FileReader extends ByteArrayInputStream{

  private int bitsRead;
  private int bitPosition;
  private int currentByte;
  private int myMark;
  private final static int NUM_BITS_IN_BYTE = 8;
  private final static int END_POSITION = -1;
  private boolean readingStarted;
  /**
   * Create a BitInputStream for a File on disk.
   */
  public FileReader( byte[] buf ) throws IOException {
    super( buf );

    myMark         = 0;
    bitsRead       = 0;
    bitPosition    = NUM_BITS_IN_BYTE-1;
    currentByte    = 0;
    readingStarted = false;
  }


  /**
   * Read a binary "1" or "0" from the File.
   */
  public int readBit() throws IOException {
    int theBit = -1;

    if( bitPosition == END_POSITION || !readingStarted ) {
      currentByte    = super.read();
      bitPosition    = NUM_BITS_IN_BYTE-1;
      readingStarted = true;
    }

    theBit = (0x01 << bitPosition) & currentByte;
    bitPosition--;

    if( theBit > 0 ) {
      theBit = 1;
    }

    return( theBit );
  }


  /**
   * Return the next byte in the File as lowest 8 bits of int.
   */
  public int read() {
    currentByte    = super.read();
    bitPosition    = END_POSITION;
    readingStarted = true;

    return( currentByte );
  }


  /**
   *
   */
  public void mark( int readAheadLimit ) {
    super.mark(readAheadLimit);
    myMark = bitPosition;
  }


  /**
   * Add needed functionality to super's reset() method. Reset to
   * the last valid position marked in the input stream.
   */
  public void reset() {
    super.pos   = super.mark-1;
    currentByte = super.read();
    bitPosition = myMark;
  }


  /**
   * Returns the number of bits still available to be read.
   */
  public int availableBits() throws IOException {
    return(  ((super.available() * 8) + (bitPosition + 1))  );
  }

}
```

In class where i call this, i do:

```
FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);

        byte[] fileBits = new byte[inputStream.available()];

        inputStream.read(fileBits, 0, inputStream.available());
        inputStream.close();

        FileReader bitIn = new FileReader(fileBits);
```

and this work correctly. 
However i have problems with big files above 100 mb because byte[] have the end.

So i want to read bigger files. Maybe some could suggest how i can improve this code ?

Thanks.

Comment: Don't use available(). Son't ignore the result of the read() call. available() doesn't return the size of the file. And read() doesn't necessarily read everything at once.

Comment: Don't call it `FileReader` unless it implements `java.io.Reader`, and also don't because it conflicts with `java.io.FileReader`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If scaling to large file sizes is important, you'd be better off not reading the entire file into memory. The downside is that handling the `IOException` in more locations can be a little messy. Also, it doesn't look like your application needs something that implements the `InputStream` API, it just needs the `readBit()` method. So, you can safely encapsulate, rather than extend, the `InputStream`.

```
class FileReader {

  private final InputStream src;

  private final byte[] bits = new byte[8192];

  private int len;

  private int pos;

  FileReader(InputStream src) { 
    this.src = src; 
  }

  int readBit() throws IOException {
    int idx = pos / 8;
    if (idx >= len) {
      int n = src.read(bits);
      if (n < 0)
        return -1;
      len = n;
      pos = 0;
      idx = 0;
    }
    return ((bits[idx] & (1 << (pos++ % 8))) == 0) ? 0 : 1;
  }

}
```

Usage would look similar.

```
FileInputStream src = new FileInputStream(file);
try {
  FileReader bitIn = new FileReader(src);
  ...
} finally {
  src.close();
}
```

If you really do want to read in the entire file, and you are working with an actual file, you can query the length of the file first.

```
File file = new File(path);
if (file.length() > Integer.MAX_VALUE)
  throw new IllegalArgumentException("File is too large: " + file.length());
int len = (int) file.length();
FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
try { 
  byte[] fileBits = new byte[len];
  for (int pos = 0; pos < len; ) {
    int n = inputStream.read(fileBits, pos, len - pos);
    if (n < 0)
      throw new EOFException();
    pos += n;
  }
  /* Use bits. */
  ...
} finally {
  inputStream.close();
}
```

Comment: In above code there       int n = src.read(bits);
I get exception

Answer (score 0):

```
org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(InputStream in, OutputStream out)
```